# Defining folder path

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have a rather curious problem.
I have this code (written by someone else). It is suppose to create couple of folders withing each other upon clicking on a specific button. It uses this:

```
string directoryCrate = "/" + comboIndustry.Text + "/" + comboCustomerName.Text + "/"
```

Now, as you see, the separator for the folders are "/". But later in the code I need to have the full path of the folder which is c:\projects and then the path to the new folder which is /Industry/Customer/...
So if I want to get the address in the clipboard it would be something like this: C"\projects/Industry/customer/... and obviously I cannot open this address in explorer! For some reason the method won't accept "\" when I try. I am quite confused. Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried a string.Replace to replace the forward slashes with back slashes?

Comment: What does this have to do with SQL Server? And why are you using `/` instead of `\ ` ? If you want to treat this text as a path, use the proper separator. BTW if the reason is "because we used the string to create hierarchies in the database" you should replace this with the purpose-built hierarchyid type.

Comment: You need to put a colon (:) after the drive name and convert the front slashes to back slashes (and also that double quote) before putting it in clipboard. Like this- C:\projects\Industry\customer\

Comment: as I said, I cannot convert the "/" to "\"... the code gives an error. It is defined like this when the folder is created like the code I sent in my question.

Comment: Panagiotis Kanavos: I don't know why! (look above, I said that the code is not written by me. I am just trying to make it work). As for SQLServer, my form is attached to a sql db and my question primarily had stuff about that, I forgot to delete the tag. I look into the hierarchies but I doubt this be the reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar
```

To get the standard directory separation char for your system. Also, if you try to do a replace, make sure to start the string with an @ so it doesn't parse the backslashes or else escaping them as:

```
string backslash = @"\";
string anotherBackslash = "\\";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"C:\Projects", directoryCrate)
string fullPath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(path)
```

or combine it into one statement.

```
string fullPath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(System.IO.Path.Combine(@"C:\Projects", directoryCrate))
```

Either of the above two should give you the complete path with backslashes.